# How to create nested collections in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to create a nested collection in Laravel. Currently I'm using multi-dimensional arrays:

```
foreach ($combination->attributes as $attr) {
        $groups['group'][$attr->group->language->name][] = $attr->language;
}
```

How would I replicate that using Laravel collections? I want to be able to leverage the lists method and groupBy methods?

Here's what the data looks like:

```
array:1 [▼
  "group" => array:2 [▼
    "Finish" => array:3 [▼
      0 => AttributeLanguage {#257 ▶}
      1 => AttributeLanguage {#234 ▶}
      2 => AttributeLanguage {#256 ▶}
    ]
    "Print Size" => array:3 [▼
      0 => AttributeLanguage {#252 ▶}
      1 => AttributeLanguage {#252 ▶}
      2 => AttributeLanguage {#252 ▶}
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: You can just pass your existing array through collect() and execute the Collection methods on it. Or you can simply resort to assembling the array using put() and push(). https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-put

Comment: You did not express your goal very well. If you only want to create collection with your current array strcuture, just simpley ```collect($groups)``` ,.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy()` for this

For Example :

```
$collection = collect([
    ['language' => 'hindi', 'product' => 'Chair'],
    ['language' => 'hindi', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
    ['language' => 'english', 'product' => 'Desk'],
]); // this is for showing array may be like 

OR 

$collection =  AttributeLanguage::all(); // this might you are using or any other way.


$grouped = $collection->groupBy('language'); // this is a collection you can see by using dd($grouped) here.
```

> showing collection as array here.

```
$grouped->toArray(); 

/*
    [
        'hindi' => [
            ['language' => 'hindi', 'product' => 'Chair'],
            ['language' => 'hindi', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
        ],
        'english' => [
            ['language' => 'english', 'product' => 'Desk'],
        ],
    ]
*/
```

for More visit Laravel Documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-groupby